# How to write ajoin query in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a hql:

```
q =session.createQuery("from DrugIndentDetails as a where a.drugbase.office.hierarchy_Id=:officeid and a.drugbase.year=:yr and a.drugbase.type=:status and a.drugbase.version=:version  group by a.drugmaster.drugId order by a.drugmaster.drugCode")
     .setParameter("yr", yr)
     .setParameter("officeid",officeid)
     .setParameter("status", status)
     .setParameter("version", version);
```

In the result of the query i want to use join query to select values from other tables

Is this possible!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sudhir Mane's answer,you can replace `TableOne` to a hibernate Entity like `User`,This is the principle of your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross join the same as SQL:

```
select [columns you need] from TableA a, TableB b
where [condition]
```

Comment: In HQL, join operator and the types of it(inner, ...), just could be used to join a table and the collection of other tables that the table owns. TO JOIN SEVERAL DIFFERENT TABLES, USE CROSS-JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the sample HQL query using Inner Join. You can specify which join required inner join, left outer join and right outer join:

```
SELECT * FROM TableOne T1 INNER JOIN TableTwo T2 ON
   T1.Column1 = T2.Column2 WHERE Column2='XXXX'
```

Comment: Yes you can create HQL using Domain Object & its attributes instead of the table below Login & USer are domain objects.                                                               FROM Login Inner join User ON Login.UserID = USer.ID WHERE CSLogin.ID =:loginId